# LFTP format_perms(int p)

Tags: c

From misc.cc in lftp. Could you please explain me the code? i try p = 600, 777 and get different expected permission.

```
// it does not prepend file type.
    const char *format_perms(int p)
    {
       static char s[10];
       memset(s,'-',9); // set - for all s[]
       if(p&0400) s[0]='r'; // set r
         if(p&0200) s[1]='w';  // set w
         if(p&0100) s[2]='x'; // set x
         if(p&0040) s[3]='r';  //set r
         if(p&0020) s[4]='w';  
         if(p&0010) s[5]='x';
         if(p&0004) s[6]='r';
         if(p&0002) s[7]='w';
         if(p&0001) s[8]='x';
         if(p&01000) s[8]=(p&0001?'t':'T');
         if(p&02000) s[5]=(p&0010?'s':'S');
         if(p&04000) s[2]=(p&0100?'s':'S');
         return s;
    }
```

What are the purpose of T and S? Thanks a lot

Comment: try to format the question...read faq..

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume you mean the 's' and 'T' in format_perms. According to the [chmod manpage](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?chmod++NetBSD-current):

> 4000    Set-user-ID-on-execution
>
> 2000    set-group-ID-on-execution
>
> 1000    sTicky bit, see [chmod(2)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?chmod+2+NetBSD-current)

Emphasis, mine.

Comment: could you please elaborate more? I am a newbie in linux. thanks a lot

Comment: Read the manpage, mate. If it's not clear after that, then don't go through source code which isn't meant for a "newbie in Linux"